# Updating Bitbucket pull request's description through Bitbucket API

Tags: api, automation, continuous-integration, bitbucket

The scenario which I'm looking at is at the process of CI - There exists a test (implemented with python script) which checks if the PR's description is in a certain format. And if it is not, the PR is **denied** (fail).

**Instead of failing**, I would like to have an update for the description in order for it to pass with default values in it.

So the main question is if there exists a way to add/update Bitbucket pull request's description through Bitbucket API? (Preferably a way for implementing in the python script of the test itself).

*Edit*: I found an [API for getting the description](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/uri-uuid), but i need to find one for updating.